# How to use webpack-dev-server along with nodemon-webpack-plugin?

Tags: webpack, nodemon

I am using a **Webpack Multiple Configuration** using array to build my **server** and **client/ui**. For server, I am using `nodemon-webpack-plugin` and for client/ui, using `webpack-dev-server` for hot-reloads. For starting the Webpack, I am using `webpack serve` command which doesn't seem to work well with `nodemon` plugin as Webpack dev-server keeps the files in memory. This is my configuration:

```
module.exports = (env) => {

  const server = {
    // Other configuration options,

    externalsPresets: { node: true },
    externals: [nodeExternals({
      allowlist: [
        'crypto-random-string'
      ]
    })],


    plugins: [
      new NodemonPlugin()
    ]
  };


  const ui = {
    // Other configuration options,

    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true,
      port: 8080,
      static: {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'ui')
      }
    }
  };

  return [server, ui];
};
```

How can I make both `webpack-dev-server` and `nodemon-webpack-plugin` happy and work together where only the UI is picked by the Webpack dev server and nodemon picks the corresponding server configuration and run it?